# Wait for click event to complete in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, model-view-controller

I have onClick event in my image which causes new tabs to be added to jQuery tabs. The event next to it will add content to this new tab.

```
$('#Image').click();
$('#controladdedbyclickabove').append( message);
```

The problem I am seeing is that the click event will not wait for the actions to complete it will continue to next statement. Due to this I cannot see the content being added to the new control that the click would have generated. How do I make the click event to wait for actions to complete before it moves to next statement?

T have to depend on triggering the click because the onClick action on #image has all parameters which I can extract as a string, but I'm not sure how to execute it.

When onClick event happens, this method is called:

```
function addTab(title, uri, userid) {
    var newTab = $("#tabs").tabs("add", uri, title);
}
```

Comment: The interesting part of the code is not given. Something asynchronous must be going on inside the click handler.

Comment: not that you mention asynchronous i think the uri part in jquery addtab is doing ajax call to pull some content for the tab.. so what is the solution if its async?

Comment: Aha, so you're using jQuery UI Tabs presumably. You need to do the `.append( message);` part inside a `create`(?) callback, specified as a `.tabs({...})` option. You also need to be slightly creative, because you want the callback action only when the new tab is initiated programatically, not when the user clicks the button.

Comment: No it can't be jQuery UI Tabs, which doesn't have an "add" method. Which tabs plugin are you using?

Comment: addTab is a custom method i wrote it uses the Jquery tabs. .tabs("add" is a jquery method

Comment: The plot thickens ..... . As the "add" method is under your control, you can modify it to accept a callback function, which fires when everything (the add action) is complete. If no callback is specified it will do nothing (especially not throw an error), and if a callback is specified, it should be called. You can pass back arguments (such as a reference to the new DOM element) so they can be used as necessary in the callback.

Comment: i might have to try to make it not a ajax call to keep it simple

Comment: Providing for a callback is simple. You've already done the hard work by writing the bulk of the add method. Edit above to show your "add" code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use callback function:

```
 if($('#Image')) {
  $('#Image').click(function() {
        $('#controladdedbyclickabove').append( message);
  });
}else {
  console.log('image object not there');
}
```

Comment: i did try with this before but didn't work. it doesn't even add the control. that means that the click is not called properly.

Comment: Or maybe you are not adding this inside document.ready
$(function(){
 // all above goes here
});

Comment: `if($('#Image'))` will always return true, even if element doesn't exist. jQuery will create empty object.... use `if($('#Image').length)` to check for existence. Need to trigger the click also ....chain `.click()` to the handler.  `$('#Image').click(function() {/*...*/}).click()`

Comment: it is inside        $(function () {, i also tried to call the function to add new tab replacing the click event. with same result.  i am using jquery tabs  var newTab = $("#chattabs").tabs("add", uri, title); onclick event was calling this addnewtab statement

Comment: tried adding click() at the end $('#Image').click(function() {/*...*/}).click(), with no success. however it does add the new tab unlike  before, but the append doesn't find the control

Comment: You can't use a callback function when triggering a click event. When calling the `click` method with a function as parameter, it won't trigger the click event, instead it will bind the function as an event handler for the event.

Answer (score 4):

You can't wait for the event to be handled, because it won't be handled until you exit your function and return control to the browser.

To run the code after the event has been handled, you need to start it after you have exited the function:

```
$('#Image').click();
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $('#controladdedbyclickabove').append( message);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways to do that.you wanna execute something when the click finished.

1: why not make your code like this

```
function addTab(title, uri, userid) {
   var newTab = $("#tabs").tabs("add", uri, title);
   $('#controladdedbyclickabove').append( message);
}
```

2: you also can define a funciton like this

```
function addTabCallback () {
  $('#controladdedbyclickabove').append( message);
}

function addTab(title, uri, userid) {
   var newTab = $("#tabs").tabs("add", uri, title);
   addTabCallback();
}
```

3: you can use observer pattern

```
function addTab(title, uri, userid) {
   var newTab = $("#tabs").tabs("add", uri, title);
   var observer = addTab.observers.shift();
   while (observer) {
      observer();
      observer = addTab.observers.shift();
   }
}
addTab.observers = [];
```

should do a little change when you trigger the click

```
addTab.observers.push(function () {
   // codes here will be executed when the click finished
   $('#controladdedbyclickabove').append( message);
});

$('#Image').click();
```

this is a sample code with observer pattern, for real, it should do some observer type check,etc.^_^.

Comment: i tried option#1 and 2 didn;t work. have not tried number 3 not sure what its doing

Answer (score 1):

i ended up passing the append message back to server where the ajax calls. so when click event calls a message is added in the control when it comes back. i could not get javascript callback to work as expected.